# What is the best audio format to upload in. Server will convert to mp3 and ogg

Tags: java, php, audioformat

Which audio format would provide the least lossy conversion into mp3 and ogg through ffmpeg.

I am tending towards wav, but I would like to make sure.

Also, I am using the SDK java audio applet to allow users to upload.  Does anyone know if there are any issues with this applet, or if there is a better option out there?

Comment: There is no "best" audio format. Each format has good points and bad points. wav is not an audio format, it's a container format that is targetted towards audio. If you allow .wav uploads, you'll need something that can handle ALL the codecs that .wav can contain.

Comment: i would suggest upload in ogg, and only convert to mp3, as ogg is not `lame` encoded ^^

Comment: Generally good first question post, but avoid signing your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, uploading files already in MP3 and OGG format would provide the least lossy conversion since you don't need to convert at all.

About the SDK java audio applet: Is this really needed? You can also upload a file using just a HTML form and PHP.

Comment: +1 for noting that the best conversion is no conversion at all, but Ogg is a container, not a format. It can contain MP3.

Comment: I'm letting users record and upload straight from the page.  I haven't come across another option (only SDK) that would allow me to do this.  I don't know of another applet that would force client side encoding into ogg and mp3, which is why I need to do it server side.  I will need both formats for the same piece of audio to provide for all major browsers.  Unless I'm missing something, or do something with flash, it's the only way that I have found.

Comment: If you want users to record sound right in the browser, then using a Java applet or Flash is indeed the best option. Another question How do you try to play the sound? With some fancy javascript? Or with the audio Tag? According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp) indeed IE and safari have trouble with OGG and FireFox and Opera have trouble with Ogg. You could indeed go for some flash player, [JWplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) is a great option.

Comment: @Qqwy, thanks.  I'll take a look at JWplayer.  So far i've just been using the audio tag, which is the exact reason I need my files in both formats.   AARRRGG, if only for conformity!!!!

Answer (score 0):

FLAC is lossless, and so is WAV.  FLAC is smaller than WAV.  If you need something that you will be converting into multiple formats, opt for a lossless format.

Comment: Thanks, FLAC would be better, as its smaller.  Do you know of any applets that would allow client side uploading in FLAC?  SDK doesn't support it.

Comment: @DavieDave, I'm not sure why you can't upload anything you want and process on the server.

Comment: That's what my first option is, but if i can find a way to get the conversion done client side, it will save my server that extra processing.